# how to get all elements in table a that are not in table b using hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

how can I get all the entries that are in table A but not in table B in Hive?

```
table A = jobs  (id, duration)
table B = other_jobs (id, duration)
```

I want all the jobs that are in A which do not appear in B, each job has a unique id
something like this picture illustrates:
http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b012877702754970c-pi

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer is:

```
SELECT jobs.* 
FROM jobs 
LEFT OUTER JOIN other_jobs 
ON (jobs.id = other_jobs.id) 
WHERE other_jobs.id IS NULL;
```